# On Gaussian Primes

Tags: math-history

Some primes in the ring of integers (17, for example) cease to behave as such in the ring of gaussian integers, while others (7, for instance) keep being prime there as well. The former are of the form $4n +1$, while the later can be written as $4n + 3$.

I would like to know who was responsible for this finding? Any reference? Was it Kummer? Or was it already Gauss? Quotation, bibliography?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Certainly, Fermat knew the result about primes that are the sum of two squares.  That's well before Gauss. Rephrasing that as about factorizations in Gaussian integers probably came about as soon as Gaussian integers were defined. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: According to that article, Dedekind was the first to give a proof of that result using Gaussian integers, but that's not the same as knowing the theorem and applying it to Gaussian integers.

Comment: Does the difference between irregular and regular primes hinge on this?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews as sometimes happened, Fermat asserted the sum-of-two-squares result but provided no proof. Euler produced the proof, definitely one that wouldn't fit in a margin. :-)

Comment: Always bad in comments here to use pronouns without using the noun elsewhere. What is 'this"? @JavierArias

Comment: @Thomas Andrews. I just wondered whether the criterion regarding 4n+3 vs 4n+1 had also inspired somehow the division between regular and irregular orimes.

Comment: Inspired and hinge are quite different terms. "Hinge" would mean "depends strongly."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gauss introduced Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Historical_background) and proved unique factorization in the ring in the same paper.

The theorem about integer primes that can be written as the sum of squares was already well-known, having been first proved by Euler.

I have no doubt that Gauss was aware that the integer primes that factor in $\mathbb Z[i]$ were exactly those of the form $4n+1$ (and, of course, $2$.)

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed an answer, and I have marked it as such.